# Getting an error trying to json.load Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make some program to tell me which lesson I have at a certain time and day.
To make it work, I put my schedule in a json file (the numbers correspond to the day number).

```
{
    "1": [
        "french",
        "french",
        "yearit",
        "geography",
        "hebrew",
        "shelah",
        "science",
        ""
    ],
    "2": [
        "sports",
        "literature",
        "math rotem",
        "geography",
        "hebrew",
        "hebrew",
        "science",
        "yearit"
    ],
    "3": [
        "yearit",
        "english",
        "math gila",
        "english",
        "yizhak",
        "yizhak",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "4": [
        "english",
        "math gila",
        "science",
        "math rotem",
        "sports",
        "literature",
        "science",
        "science"
    ],
    "5": [
        "life skills",
        "yizhak",
        "french",
        "yizhak",
        "math gila",
        "italian",
        "italian",
        "math gila"
    ],
    "6": [
        "yizhak",
        "english",
        "english",
        "math gila",
        "science",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    "7": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "", 
    ],
}
```

I used this code to turn it into a python dictionary:

```
import json
with open('schedule.json', 'r') as f:
    schedule = json.load(f)
    
print(schedule)
```

But it gave me this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\everything\coding lol\Python\CheckZoom\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    schedule = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 71 column 2 (char 721)
```

How can I solve this error? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you have 2 extra commas in your JSON file which makes it not valid JSON - check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. I checked if my json code was valid, but then I did some editing and forgot to check it again

Answer (score 0):

As @buran pointed out, you have extra commas at the end of the file, specifically here:

```
    "7": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "", # this is an extra comma
    ], # this is an extra comma
}
```

But the file can still be processed by using the [`ast.literal_eval` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval):

```py
import ast

with open('schedule.json', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
schedule = ast.literal_eval(text)
print(schedule)
```

Prints:

```
{'1': ['french', 'french', 'yearit', 'geography', 'hebrew', 'shelah', 'science', ''], '2': ['sports', 'literature', 'math rotem', 'geography', 'hebrew', 'hebrew', 'science', 'yearit'], '3': ['yearit', 'english', 'math gila', 'english', 'yizhak', 'yizhak', '', ''], '4': ['english', 'math gila', 'science', 'math rotem', 'sports', 'literature', 'science', 'science'], '5': ['life skills', 'yizhak', 'french', 'yizhak', 'math gila', 'italian', 'italian', 'math gila'], '6': ['yizhak', 'english', 'english', 'math gila', 'science', '', '', ''], '7': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Share an example of oneline style

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

schedule = json.loads(Path('schedule.json').read_text())
```